# How do they differ "separate payment" and "divided payment"

Tags: word-choice

How do they differ "separate payment" and "divided payment" when total amount for more than 2 persons  should be divided for each person?

Just one more query on "2 persons" used in the above sentence, is it correct to be used 2 persons as the plural of person should be "people"?

Comment: I guess you should use _split payment_. Also, you should separate out your second question. Only one question should be asked in one question :)

Comment: Neither "separate payment" nor "divided payment" has any special meaning so you need to work from the context and the dictionary. Please provide examples of what you are struggling with.

Comment: "Divided" literally means "split in two" and nothing else, but almost no-one even recognises, let alone uses that distinction. Modern usage of "divided" is "split among however-many-you-like".

Comment: Depending on the context, either "persons" or "people" could be the plural of "person", because there cannot be "one (or a) people".

If you wish to refer to people as individuals, then strictly "2 (or 37) persons" would be correct but it would also be old-fashioned, if not yet archaic.

If you wish to refer to people as a group, crowd or mob, then strictly "2 (or 37) people" would be correct, as well as being more modern

Comment: In the US at least, we typically will ask for “separate checks” or tell them we are “paying separately” if we each want to pay for exactly what we ordered.  We might tell the waiter to split it down the middle to share the cost equally between two people or split it (or divide it) in 3 (or 4 ...)  to share equally among more than two people.

Comment: @Jim the UK case is similar (except we'd say "bill" instead of "check"). I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @ChrisH - We also use “bill” sometimes- I know I have, and I also use check. It’s whatever trips off the tongue first I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I can give you a solid answer for 1), but it could be that separate payment is everyone paying for their own meals while divided payment might be each person paying an equal amount regardless of what they ordered.

As for 2), both "persons" and "people" can be used as the plural of "person". "Persons" is generally used in formal documents such as contracts. Keep in mind that "peoples" has another meaning altogether - it refers to an ethnic group or a community of people (e.g. tribes).

Comment: Both of them have a quite big different meaning even though both words "separate" and "divided" have similar concept, but I totally understanding that "divided" is described as a concept of "half". On the other hand, separate is described as a concept of allocation of defined amount.